# Updated .gitignore file but status still reports unstaged files

Tags: git, gitignore

Other posts on this topic have solvable issues like the *.gitignore* file was in the wrong place or the match syntax was wrong.

My case is very simple:

.gitignore file:

```
*.pkl
```

Yet when I run `git status`:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   data.pkl
```

I expect it has something to do with the matching files being included in previous commits or some issue with other branches? Anyone have any bright ideas of how to investigate this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is because git is already tracking your `data.pkl` file.
Any new file whose extension is **.pkl** would be ignored, but you need to delete manually all other files.

You should run this command:

```
git rm --cached data.pkl
```

This would remove your file from version control while keeping the existing file.